# Android - flashlight intensity control

Tags: android

I have a new [phone](https://www.gsmarena.com/t_mobile_revvl_6-11937.php), which unfortunately, unlike the old one, cannot control the flashlight intensity.

Is there any app where this can't be set, please? I already tried some but couldn't find it anywhere.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

So today I finally updated to Android 13 and it is still not possible to regulate the flashlight.

Comment: That much depends on the Android version used. Since Android 13, this can be controlled by an app (before it seems it depended on the device), and you could use e.g. [FlashDim](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.cyb3rko.flashdim/). Could you please specify which Android version you're on – and whether apps requiring root/Magisk/Xposed would be acceptable solutions?

Comment: The old phone may have ended up on Android 11, but this is a Samsung that can control the light thanks to One UI. The new phone still has Android 12. However, I have no idea when the update to Android 13 will be released. Honestly, I don't even have confirmation if it will actually get Android 13, but I hope so.

Comment: @Izzy As I already wrote in the question itself, it is not possible even after the update.

Comment: Sorry to hear. Might be a restriction by the "ROM makers" then, I don't know. Maybe try contacting the manufacturer's support?